# Is there a way to generate columns in a view based on table row data?

Tags: postgresql, function, view, jsonb

I have this table which contains the settings of an app & I just want to show it in the view. The data of each setting is stored as a row.

```
Code (varchar64)| Value (varchar1000)
----------------------
ALLOW_MAC_ADDR  | 1
----------------------
ALLOW_SAVE      | 1
----------------------
USER_ALIAS      | James
```

Now this is where it gets kinda complicated, I have to convert these rows into a `jsonb` at the view. The key for `value` column name has to be based on the value of the `Code` column data.

Here is an example of prefered jsonb:

`[dt:{ALLOW_MAC_ADDR: 1, ALLOW_SAVE: 1, USER_ALIAS: 'James'}]`

I'm thinking of doing some like this in my view:

`SELECT .. FROM generate_jsonb()`

So how do I achieve such jsonb?

EDIT: I'm using v9.6 if that helps.

Comment: what's your postgres version? what's wrong with existing json functions?..

Comment: Nothing wrong with the version, I just need an efficient example to generate such jsonb

Comment: please update your post with your postgres version - there is very different json support for json back in years

Comment: The version: v9.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

> aggregate function json_object_agg which aggregates pairs of values
>   into a JSON object

eg:

```
t=# create table tt(code text, value text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into tt values('ALLOW_MAC_ADDR',1),('USER_ALIAS','James');
INSERT 0 2
t=# select json_object_agg(code,value) from tt;
                  json_object_agg
----------------------------------------------------
 { "ALLOW_MAC_ADDR" : "1", "USER_ALIAS" : "James" }
(1 row)
```

Comment: Those are hard coded, I'm looking for something that selects the data of `code` & using it as the key & looping through the entire records