# How do I edit this json?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, view, postgrest

I have this code in my VIEW:

```
SELECT json_object_agg(code,value) FROM table1
```

It generates this in my postgREST api:

```
[{"json_object_agg":"{code1: value1, code2: value2, ...}"]
```

I want to remove the `json_object_agg` to make it like this:

```
[{code1: value1, code2: value2, ...}]
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have empty result set name. I assume this is related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214735/is-there-a-way-to-generate-columns-in-a-view-based-on-table-row-data) where you were getting

```
t=# select json_object_agg(code,value) from tt;
                  json_object_agg
----------------------------------------------------
 { "ALLOW_MAC_ADDR" : "1", "USER_ALIAS" : "James" }
```

So if you try to name the column with empty value (closest I can think of from your post requirements), you get the error:

```
t=# select json_object_agg(code,value) "" from tt;
ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: select json_object_agg(code,value) "" from tt;
                                       ^
```

Of course you can mokey hack it with space character, like:

```
t=# select json_object_agg(code,value) " " from tt;

----------------------------------------------------
 { "ALLOW_MAC_ADDR" : "1", "USER_ALIAS" : "James" }
```

which is ALMOST no name, but I assume you have to modify your "postgREST api" in order to do it properly - ignoring the result set attribute name